# Continuous Carousel using React and styled-components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, carousel, styled-components

I'm trying to recreate a carousel that is continuous using react and styled-components without any dependencies. The continuous carousel should work by appending the first element to the last once it reaches the last element. I'm new to react and styled-components.

example : [Continuous Carousel](https://codepen.io/desandro/pen/emjrBm)

```
<p><code>wrapAround: true</code></p>

<!-- Flickity HTML init -->
<div class="gallery js-flickity"
  data-flickity-options='{ "wrapAround": true }'>
  <div class="gallery-cell"></div>
  <div class="gallery-cell"></div>
  <div class="gallery-cell"></div>
  <div class="gallery-cell"></div>
  <div class="gallery-cell"></div>
</div>
```

This is done by Flickity. I'm trying to recreate the functionality using react and styled-components only